# ASP.Net MVC5 Date picker

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a calendar date-picker in my Code first ASP.Net application.

Currently, this is what my code looks like in the model called "Student.cs"

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/mm/dd}")]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1995/01/01", "2016/12/31")]
public DateTime DateOfbirth { get; set; }
```

This, however, gives me a combo-box type datepicker which I'm also struggling to set the format of.

I'd like to implement the following jQuery datepicker:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
 </script>
```

And then, using

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

in the view html file, I should be able to have a calendar for my date of birth field?

I'm not sure of where to place the above script though, and also I'm not sure where to change the input type in the View file.
Currently, the view file controls the date using the following code which I'm not sure of how to change in order to implement the 'datepicker' component.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfbirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfbirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfbirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower "mm" stands for minutes. Capital "MM" stands for month.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
```

Also, your jQuery function will only work after you load the jQuery library, so if it loads at the end of the _Layout.cshtml DOM, like it usually does, you need to place the script in a bundle after the library is loaded.

You also don't want a second `<input>` tag, which `EditorFor` already does. Just write it like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfbirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "datepicker" } })
```

I think this is all you need to fix.

I'll show you what my culture function looks like:

```
$(function () {
    $("[type=datetime]").datepicker({
        closeText: 'Fechar',
        prevText: '',
        nextText: '',
        currentText: 'Hoje',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar&ccedil;o', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho',
        'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Ter&ccedil;a-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sabado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Comment: I have made those changes, however it still shows me the same picker as before. I added the script in at the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml file after the library is loaded, does that suffice? or should it be in a different file?

Comment: As long as it loads after the jQuery library in _Layout.cshtml, you can put it anywhere you want.

Comment: Apparently you may need a configuration script alongside your jQuery library to set your culture standard for the "minified" month names and whatnot, as in "Jan" for "January" and so on.